# Import csv into mongo db

Tags: c#, mongodb, csv

I have to import my file excel csv to mongodb, but I want use code c#.

```cs
public class AnimalRetriever : IAnimalRetriever
{
    private readonly MongoClient _mongoClient;

    public AnimalRetriever()
    {
        _mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    }

    private List<Animal> GetByContinent(string continent)
    {
        _mongoClient.GetDatabase("local")
                    .GetCollection<Animal>("Animal")
                    .ReplaceOne(
                        filter: new BsonDocument("Continent", continent),
                        options: new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true },
                        replacement: animal.csv); //file di testo da leggere invece di newDoc(csv extension)

        return _mongoClient.GetDatabase("local")
                           .GetCollection<Animal>("Continent")
                           .Find("{\"Continent\":\"" + continent + "\"}")
                           .ToList();
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve here. do you want to create documents in your mongodb collecition with data imported from a csv file? if so, pls add some sample lines from the csv file.

Comment: I have a csv file from excel and I want to bring this data to a mongo database. But I want to transfer this excel data to mongo using the code c #.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using FactoryExample.Continent;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using CsvHelper;

namespace FactoryExample
{
    class MainApp
    {
        public static void Main()
        { try
            {
                var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
                var db = client.GetDatabase("local");
                var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Animal");
var reader = new StreamReader("animal.csv");
                var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Animals>();


                var dizionario = new Dictionary<string,Animal>();


                foreach (var animal in records)
                {

                    if (dizionario.ContainsKey(animal.Continent))
                    {
                        dizionario[animal.Continent].Carnivor.Add(animal.Carnivor);
                        dizionario[animal.Continent].Herbivor.Add(animal.Herbivor);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var newanimal = new Animal
                        {
                            Continent = animal.Continent,
                            Carnivor = new List<string>(),
                            Herbivor = new List<string>()
                        };


                        newanimal.Carnivor.Add(animal.Carnivor);
                        newanimal.Herbivor.Add(animal.Herbivor);
                        dizionario.Add(newanimal.Continent,newanimal);
                    }
                   }
}

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error!!");
                Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

            //Console.Read();

            var continentFactory = ContinentFactory.Get(ContinentType.AMERICA);
            var carnivore = continentFactory.GetCarnivore();
            var herbivore = continentFactory.GetHerbivore();

            foreach (var h in herbivore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(h);
            }

            foreach (var c in carnivore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```